# error in accessing variable of main activity's class from mapactivity

Tags: android, eclipse, google-maps, variables

it seems to be a typical question but its not i am facing problem in accessing a variable of main activity's onitemselected class(spinner class)from mapavtivity

in main avtivity map is shown on button click

now i want to use a variable of main activity's class from mapctivity
mapactivity code

```
      String dest ;

      OnItemSelectedListener place = new OnItemSelectedListener();
      dest = place.onItemSelected();
```

now onitemselected class

```
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View arg1, int arg2,
        long arg3) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

  name = "Destination:" + parent.getSelectedItem().toString()+ "\n";

    etTextOut.setText(name);



}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

public String onItemSelected() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //dest = name;

    return name;

}
```

}

problem is in mapactivity the variable is null it cannot get value

tell me what i am doing wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand the way your program is set up but from what I understand you have a main `Activity` which has a spinner in it.

First make sure you're actually setting the `onItemSelectedlistener` to the spinner after you create it.

```
OnItemSelectedListener place = new OnItemSelectedListener();
//Replace "spinnerId" with the id you have set for your spinner in your layout
Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerId);
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(place);
```

Then if you want to start the `MapActivity` and have it have access to the "name" value, you'll have to pass the value in the intent you use to start the activity.

```
String dest = place.onItemSelected(); 
//You might want to rename this method to something clearer like "getName" but that's just me.
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MapActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("DestValue", dest);
startActivity(intent);
```

Now, in your `MapActivity`, you will have access to this value by using:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String dest = intent.getStringExtra("DestValue");
```

If your main activity is not starting the MapActivity, you can also try looking into `SharedPreferences` to pass values between activities.

Hope this was helpful.

Corrected Answer:

Try this in your activity.  It should work:

```
private EditTextBox etTextOut;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceBundle){
    EditTextBox etTextOut = (EditTextBox) findViewById(R.id.etTextOutId);
    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerId);
    OnItemSelectedListener spinnerListener = new OnItemSelectedListener{

        private String name;

        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id){
            name = name = "Destination:" + parent.getSelectedItem().toString()+ "\n";
            etTextOut.setText(name);
        }

        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent){}

        public String getName(){
            return name;
        }
    }

     spinner.setOnItemClickListener(spinnerListener);

}
```

Comment: i want to set slected spinner value to edittextbox but the problem is my edittextbox has also got other values but i just want place name      spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener(etTextOut));
     
      OnItemSelectedListener p = new OnItemSelectedListener();
      place = p.name; i applied this but same result place got null value

Comment: I edited my answer. Try that.  After that block of code in your activity you should be able to use `dest = spinnerListener.getName()` to pass the value to another activity with an intent or SharedPreferences.